# Is it possible to run a python function using dictionaries?

Tags: python

Ok so here's my code:

```
import subprocess
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS

knownCommands = {"open lunar client": subprocess.call('C:/Users/Joshua/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Lunar Client')}

def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text)
    filename = "voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)

def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))

        return said
speak("Hello. I am SuperAssitant 1. How can I help you today?")


text = get_audio()
if text == "open lunar client":
    subprocess.call('C:/Users/Joshua/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Lunar Client')
```

I'm wondering if I can run a value that's in a dictionary, in this case `knownCommands`. If you don't understand what I mean, here's an example:

1. I have a dictionary with a python line as the value.
2. I want to be able to run that line without typing it in again.

Comment: "I have a dictionary with a python line as the value" that doesn't make any sense. That isn't what your dictionary contains, it contains the *result* of calling `subprocess.call`

Comment: But in python, functions are first class objects (everything is an object pretty much) so you could out a function in your dict if you wanted to

Comment: What do you mean by "python line"? Do you mean a function? And what do you mean by "run that line"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how would I do that?

Comment: The same way you out any other object in a dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: If you know you are going to call `subprocess.call` for every `knownCommand` just store the command as a string:

```py
knownCommands = {'open lunar client': 'C:/Users/Joshua/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start  Menu/Programs/Lunar Client'}

text = get_audio()
command = knownCommands.get(text)
if command:
  subprocess.call(command)
```

Option 2: If each command can have a different behaviour, use a lambda:

```py
knownCommands = {'open lunar client': lambda: subprocess.call('C:/Users/Joshua/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Lunar Client')}

text = get_audio()
command = knownCommands.get(text)
if command:
  command()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to store a function as a value in a dictionary. Demonstrating in iPython:

```
In [1]: def hello_world():
   ...:     print("Hello World!")
   ...: 

In [2]: dictionary = {'hello': hello_world}

In [3]: dictionary['hello']
Out[3]: <function __main__.hello_world()>

In [4]: dictionary['hello']()
Hello World!
```